Is there an on topic way to ask about a "common knowledge" issue arising from an on-topic answer which seems wrong?
I recently have read this thread: How to calculate Sharpe Ratio from $ returns?. I realised that the two methods given as an answer by the accepted post are not consistent, they give different results. I asked about this here: Which Sharpe ratio calculation is correct [closed]. But, this got closed because:

Basic financial questions are off-topic as they are assumed to be
common knowledge for those studying or working in the field of
quantitative finance.

Is there a way to ask about the inconsistency in that answer without being off-topic?

With a comment under the original answer as you did. As pointed out in the comments, the methods are not the same, so different results are to be expected. One uses dollar returns and the other percent returns. Note that the original question was specifically asking about a pairs trading strategy where dollar returns might make more sense.
